# Creating GPG encrypted tar.gz Backup fails

Tags: linux, backup, compression, gnupg, tar

I hope this kind of question is ok here ;)

I am on Debian 10 Buster, trying to create an (GPG) encrypted, compressed tar file without intermediary files. I found this article[1] on the web which pointed me to this command:

`tar -cvzf - /path/to/folder/ | gpg2 -e -r "key-id" > /mnt/backup/backup.tar.gz.enc`

But to me, it looks like I only get an encrypted tarball with no compression. What am I doing wrong?

[1] https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-compressed-encrypted-archives-with-tar-and-gpg
in the mix with
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GnuPG/#Verschluesseln (German, sorry) and
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-individual-files-with-gpg#h8-basic-encryption

Comment: Why do you think it's not compressed?

Comment: I think that encrypted files don't compress very well. Encrypted files are designed to look like like random data, so compression will not save any space. @tripleee is that what you meant?

Comment: No, I was asking why you think this isn't compressed. The command line you quoted will first compress, then encrypt. (Perhaps it is a bit misleading to have `.enc` in the middle of the file name, rather than at the end, though.)

Comment: I don't think it is compressed, because the file has almost the same size as the (du -sh) disk usage of the folder. Also, in my opinion, my command should first tar and zip and then compress. And yes, you are right, @triplee the file ending is not the best. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption is irrelevant: `tar` doesn't know where its output goes next. You could run just `tar -cvzf somefile.tar.gz /path/to/folder/` to see that the produced file is larger than you expect too. That would be a good first troubleshooting step.

The `z` in `tar -cvzf` enables passing the output through `gzip`, which will compress it. So your data is being compressed.

Some data is incompressible or barely compressible though, in extreme cases producing output larger than before compression. That's the case here. You just can't squeeze this input any further.

Comment: Oh wow, your last paragraph about incrompressible files made me think again. Some other settings which I changed but completely forgot about, created some other tar.gz files inside of the folderstructure I want to compress-and-encrypt. Bad trap, if one is to blind and fixed on just one possible end of the problem. So everything works as expected.